# android compile error "undefined reference to" with arm64-v8a ABI

Tags: makefile, protocol-buffers, cocos2d-x, arm64

Environment:

```
protocol buffer: 2.5.0
ndk: android-ndk-r13b
ant: apache-ant-1.9.4
cocos2d-x: 3.12
os: mac 10.12
```

I have been compiling with `APP_ABI = armeabi-v7a` for a long time (from .h and .cc files from https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v2.5.0) and everything works just fine.

But recently I have to add `arm64-v8a` to the APP_ABI and I began to get the follow errors:

```
stubs/once.h:125: undefined reference to 
google::protobuf::internal::Acquire_Load(long const volatile*)
```

Then I checked and find `Acquire_Load` is declared in `stubs/atomicops.h` with a macro:

```
#ifdef GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_ARCH_64_BIT
// ......
Atomic64 Acquire_Load(volatile const Atomic64* ptr);
// ......
#endif  // GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_ARCH_64_BIT
```

And the macro `GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_ARCH_64_BIT` is defined in `stubs/platform_macros.h` :

```
#if defined(_M_X64) || defined(__x86_64__)
#define GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_ARCH_X64 1
#define GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_ARCH_64_BIT 1
#elif defined(_M_IX86) || defined(__i386__)
#define GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_ARCH_IA32 1
#define GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_ARCH_32_BIT 1
#elif defined(__QNX__)
#define GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_ARCH_ARM_QNX 1
#define GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_ARCH_32_BIT 1
#elif defined(__ARMEL__)
#define GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_ARCH_ARM 1
#define GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_ARCH_32_BIT 1
#elif defined(__MIPSEL__)
#define GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_ARCH_MIPS 1
#define GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_ARCH_32_BIT 1
#elif defined(__pnacl__)
#define GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_ARCH_32_BIT 1
#elif defined(__ppc__)
#define GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_ARCH_PPC 1
#define GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_ARCH_32_BIT 1
#elif defined(__aarch64__)
#define GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_ARCH_ARM 1
#define GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_ARCH_64_BIT 1
#else
#error Host architecture was not detected as supported by protobuf
#endif
```

I am not very familiar with compiling stuffs so can not figure out where goes wrong.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: With all due respect, **r13** is a very old version of Android NDK. You may also want to move to a more up-to-date [release of protobuf](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases).

Answer (score 0):

Your ProtoBuf 2 version does not support `Arm64 AtomicOps`.

You can upgrade or patch to support it. Please check the following [protobuf commit](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/commit/2ca19bd8066821a56f193e7fca47139b25c617ad).